# Regular Expression: Prevent from matching empty string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have this regex string

```
(hour)?|(minute)?|(second)?
```

which will match hourminutesecond or hourminute or hoursecond...

However, the regex also match an empty string ""

How can I exclude the empty string from the list of matches?

Comment: You can try: `(?=.)(hour|minute|second)?`

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix here would be to add a positive lookahead which asserts that at least one character be present:

```regex
(?=.)(?:hour)?(?:minute)?(?:second)?
```

Note that the `|` in your current pattern are not doing what you think they are.  The `?` you place after each time term already make each term optional.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the separated capture groups for further processing, you could match at least one of the alternatives making none of them optional using a non capture group `(?:`

```
(?:hour|minute|second)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHmeZz/1)